# Add a new directive inside a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of data which is displayed using a directive inside a ng-repeat. When the user clicks a button, it'll add a new object in this array so a new instance of that directive must be executed. My HTML at the moment:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="c in commissions" commission="c.commission" index="{{$index}}"></li>
</ul>
```

When the user clicks the "add" button, the following function is executed (coffeescript):

```
$scope.newCommission = function() {
  var commission;
  commission = {
    new_commission: true
  };
  return $scope.commissions.push(commission);
};
```

My directive atm:

```
var Commission;

Commission = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '/assets/template/commission/list.html',
    controller: 'ProductEditCtrl',
    scope: {
      commission: '=',
      index: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
      var commission;
      commission = scope.commission;
      commission.index = scope.index;
      scope.editable = false;
      scope.changeType = function(type) {
        return commission.type = type;
      };
      scope.removeCommission = function() {
        return ctrl.deleteCommission(commission.index, commission.id);
      };
      scope.saveCommission = function() {
        var obj;
        obj = {
          seller_id: commission.seller.id,
          type: commission.type,
          value: commission.value
        };
        ctrl.changeCommission(commission.id, obj);
        return scope.editable = false;
      };
      return scope.turnEditable = function() {
        return scope.editable = true;
      };
    }
  };
};
```

angular.module('horus.products').directive('commission', Commission);

So, what happens is this, a new is added into my list and it compiles the template from my directive, but it gives me an error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'index' of undefined
>       at link (http://horus.dev/assets/app/modules/products/directives/commission.js?body=1:17:26)
>       at http://horus.dev/assets/angular/angular.js?body=1:7036:44
>       at nodeLinkFn (http://horus.dev/assets/angular/angular.js?body=1:6634:13)
>       at delayedNodeLinkFn (http://horus.dev/assets/angular/angular.js?body=1:6856:11)
>       at compositeLinkFn (http://horus.dev/assets/angular/angular.js?body=1:6029:13)
>       at publicLinkFn (http://horus.dev/assets/angular/angular.js?body=1:5924:30)
>       at boundTranscludeFn (http://horus.dev/assets/angular/angular.js?body=1:6049:21)
>       at controllersBoundTransclude (http://horus.dev/assets/angular/angular.js?body=1:6655:18)
>       at ngRepeatAction (http://horus.dev/assets/angular/angular.js?body=1:20345:15)
>       at Object.$watchCollectionAction [as fn] (http://horus.dev/assets/angular/angular.js?body=1:12269:13)

Any ideas why this is happening and how can I fix this? Is the way I`m doing this the best approach for adding a new directive in a ng-repeat?

Comment: The directive is an attribute without values <... commission ...> is only a flag to bind the element to a concrete type

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my bug, it was caused by a problem the way I defined the objects which were being inserted into my array.. so dumb haha